# Write a file from within a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am trying to write out a file programmatically in a Jupyter notebook. When I do an open it I get an error. Here is my code:
with open(path_and_filename,"a") as f:
for line in the_list:
f.write(line)

I get this error:
280         f"IPython won't let you open fd={file} by default "
281         "as it is likely to crash IPython. If you know what you are doing, "
282         "you can use builtins' open."

I can't seem to find the builtins' open. Can someone provide me a sample. of how to use it?

Comment: Please post the full traceback in the future. As well as more of the code in context. Preferably a minimal reproducible example. The error you show doesn't match the code have shared so far. See how the error says ` open fd={file}`? What you shared doesn't match that at all. No `fd`. No `{file]`. Makes it hard to tell you what is going on here.  Please read and follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the future. Other minor things: This is a Python question, nothing to do with Jupyter. In the future, if you want to tell if the issue involves ...

Comment: <continued> Jupyter, run the same code directly in the Python interpreter (also known as console in some places). (IPython also has a interpreter / console.) Or run the code as a traditional Python script on the command line. (IPython can run scripts, too.) If the code run in one of those different places shows the same issue, Jupyter isn't involved. Once you get more experience you can do that more as a thought experiment for determining **how & where to search around for your own help** or what keyword tags you want in your post if you cannot find the solution yourself.

Comment: As to your issue, have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76470277/8508004)? Or have you seen here [here](https://uio-cell.github.io/programming-for-lawyers/docs/05_files_exceptions.html#exceptions). You'll see what you are reporting is fairly standard boiler plate for pointing out a file or directory wrong. You may be able to troubleshoot using the additional examples there or start by hardcoding in your file and path and see if that works and then investigate how `path_and_filename` compares to the hardcoded version that works. Often putting your file in the same directory as ...

Comment: <continued> your running `.ipynb` file, you can just use the file name to verify it will open and then introduce trying to add in the filepath yourself. Point is a lot of this isn't going to be solved by us with the limited information and tiny code snippet you've provided or without access to your system. "I can't seem to find the builtins' open. " oops, I forgot to complete my thought. I was saying the thing about the builtins' open is old boilerplate and isn't going to help you. And now I see the `open fd={file}` comes from that boilerplate, too. My point about your snippet being out of ...

Comment: <continued> remains. We cannot tell what `path_and_filename` is or comes from from your little shared code snippet without more context.